# Calling a custom footer in Genesis based on page template

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I am using the Genesis framework and need to load a custom footer when a certain page template loads, but I am having issues passing the page template file name into the function. I cannot use the slug because the template can be used for multiple pages, so I really need to use the template file name instead. I believe I'm on the right path with what I have so far, but I don't quite understand what I'm reading about get_query_var and how it can help pass the value into my function. 
So far my code is as follows:

```
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer' );

if (is_page_template( 'page-alternate.php' )) {
    add_action( 'genesis_footer', 'do_alternate_footer' );
} else {
    add_action( 'genesis_footer', 'do_main_footer' );
}

function do_alternate_footer() {
    echo 'xxx';
}
function do_main_footer() {
    echo 'yyy';
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Why can't you add your code directly to the page template file?

Answer (score 0):

The "Is Page Template" function actually looks for the template page name not the file so in this example if the page template name was "alternate" you would have:

```
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer' );
$CurrPageTemplate = get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() );

if ($CurrPageTemplate == 'page-alternate.php' ) {
    add_action( 'genesis_footer', 'do_alternate_footer' );
} else {
    add_action( 'genesis_footer', 'do_main_footer' );
}

function do_alternate_footer() {
    echo 'xxx';
}
function do_main_footer() {
    echo 'yyy';
}
```

See how you go with that.

Comment: Thanks Lewis. Unfortunately that didn't resolve the issue, but it helps to know that its looking for the template name and not the file name.

Comment: You can find the template name in the top of the template file

Comment: Yes I know. I changed my function call to the page name, but it didn't resolve the issue. I think the issue is that I need to run a get_query_var but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: Did you change it to the page name or the template name?

Comment: My template name is:  //Template Name: Home Alternate, so I changed my code to   if (is_page_template( 'Home Alternate' )) {

Comment: I've updated the code to use the "Get_Page_Template_Slug" let me know how you go with that.

Comment: That didn't work, but I ran a var_dump and for some reason the queried object is pointing to the parent theme page.php, not the child theme custom file I made, even though its clearly using the child theme.

Comment: So you made a child theme and created a new page template in that child theme called 'Home Alternate' you've applied that template to the page and its still saying it's using the parent theme template?